# Show that that the following conditional probability equation holds

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with finite means.  Prove that

$$ \min E(Y-g(X))^2 =E(Y-E(Y\mid X))^2$$

holds, where $g(x)$ ranges over all functions and the min is of $g(x)$.  I honestly have no idea where to start with this equality.  Can someone perhaps guide me as to what I need to do with the min?  I think that's the biggest trouble right now. Is there some identity that can used to easily solve this?

Comment: You can think of $\mathbb E[Y\mid X]$ as the projection of $Y$ onto $L^2(\Omega, \sigma(X), \mathbb P)$, with respect to the inner product $\langle X,Y\rangle = \mathbb E[XY]$.

Comment: Can you perhaps put this into simpler terms?  I mean we haven't even used linear algebra this segment of our course yet...

Comment: Oh, I misread the problem.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\mathbb E[Y - \mathbb E[Y\mid X]]= \mathbb E[Y] - \mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y\mid X]]= \mathbb E[Y] - \mathbb E[Y] = 0. $$
It follows that for any measurable $g$, 
$$0= \mathbb E[Y - \mathbb E[Y\mid X]]^2\leqslant \mathbb E[Y-g(X)]^2.$$